# ssrs iiF STATEMENT to filter a dataset

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to write an IIf statement that basically filters my table base on the column chosen.

I have a bandorder column with values between 1 -5 and I want my IIF statement to replicate a case statement like:

```
Case when bandorder = 1 then Sum(Fields!Total_Producer.Value) else 0 end.
```

It seems basic but my IIF statement below is bringing back all the records rather than filter based on the bandorder chosen.

```
=iif(Fields!BandOrder.Value = 1,Sum(Fields!Total_Producer.Value),0)
```

Comment: Where are you using the iif statement? In a table filter? In the summary row?

Comment: I have fixed it. I changed 0 to Nothing  and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it. I changed 0 to Nothing and it worked